# Laravel 5.1 Routing with hashtag

Tags: laravel-5

I have an app where I have to call a chat page using this link : bitfood.com/#/chat,

In laravel routes I tried this :

```
Route::get('/#/chat', function(){
return view ('appchat');
});
```

or

```
Route::get('#/chat', function(){
return view ('appchat');
});
```

But the page appchat is not opening, it stays in bitfood.com home page.
I can not change the url in the app, I have to fix it in laravel. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Using # on URL treats the next string as an ID. It's better to use word slug than using # on your URL.

Comment: I have to fix it in routes, I can not edit the application's code.